# C reading struct from text file

Tags: c, file, struct

I have an array of structures stored as text; each array item begins with a number followed by a closing bracket, followed by the data for each struct member on a line on its own. For example

```
1)
Andrew
Bilous
Andriyovuch
director
1
1000
2)
... and so on...
```

Can you help me to write a loop that will read each one into a single array of structures

```
struct spivrob {
    char *name;
    char *surname;
    char *pobat;
    char *posada;
    int staz;
    int oklad;
} tab[6];
FILE *fo;
fo = fopen("C:\\Users\\andyb\\Desktop\\test7.txt","r");
```

Comment: Can you provide the contents of the `test7.txt` file?

Comment: Sry,I thought that you can see my screenshot

Comment: @BenWainwright is it good now?

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this, other than to check it compiles, but it should do the trick

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* initAndGetNextLine(FILE* fo, size_t length);
int getNextLineLength(FILE* fo);

int main()
{
   struct spivrob {
      char *name;
      char *surname;
      char *pobat;
      char *posada;
      int staz;
      int oklad;
   } tab[6];

   FILE *fo = fopen("C:\\Users\\andyb\\Desktop\\test7.txt","r");

   char*  line   = NULL;
   size_t length = 0;
   int    i      = 0;
   int    j      = -1;

   while(!feof(fo) && !ferror(fo))  {
      int len         = getNextLineLength(fo);
      char* newString = (i %7 < 5)? initAndGetNextLine(fo, len) : NULL;
      switch(i % 7) {
        case 0: j++;
        case 1: tab[j].name = newString; break;
        case 2: tab[j].surname = newString; break;
        case 3: tab[j].pobat = newString; break;
        case 4: tab[j].posada = newString; break;
        case 5: tab[j].staz = atoi(line); break;
        case 6: tab[j].oklad = atoi(line); break;
      }
      i++;
   } 
}

int getNextLineLength(FILE* fo)
{
   char c;
   int i = 0; 
   do {
      c = fgetc(fo);
      i++;
   } while(c != '\n' && !feof(fo) && !ferror(fo));
   fseek(fo, -i, SEEK_CUR);
   return i; 
}

char* initAndGetNextLine(FILE* fo, size_t length) 
{
   char* newString = malloc(length * sizeof(char) + 1);
   fgets(newString, length, fo);
   newString[length] = '\0';
   return newString;
}
```

Comment: @BenWainwright.Thank you for answer,but i get an error.Compiler tells:undefined reference to 'getline'.I guess that is because I don`t have needed #include

Comment: Did you put all three includes from the top of my answer in?

Comment: Yes,I did.I think,this func is from c++,isn`t it?

Comment: No it's from the c standard library.

Comment: It still doesnt work,program stops working and compiler says:"Process terminated with status -1073741510".I run debugger and see that the problem is in cycle while.I tryed to add return 0 to func main() and fclose for file fo but that still doesnt work